# Website / kids monitoring

Tags: security, logging

Mom needs to spy on baby sister / 11yo. What's the best option? We're looking for the following:

- Baby uses MacBook Air
- Copy of all emails sent/received
- List of websites accessed
- List of account/passwords logged in with
- Copy of all "communications" like Facebook IM's, GChat, etc
- Mom-friendly reporting without further phone calls to me

We have physical access and control of the machine, Linux server in the basement, and a budget. Is this possible?

---

Also some of the things we looked at:

- www.spectorsoft.com/eBlaster
- Charles proxy
- mitmproxy.org

Comment: Just unplug all appliances, either something is horribly wrong or someone is far too paranoid of what the world has to offer...

Comment: We sat down and discussed the permanence of the internet before. She had posted some things before that are now in the permanent internet memory and we wish weren't. Now it is time to check compliance.

Comment: The good thing about eblaster is you can get a warning if they post something like a phone number or address that you can provide. No reason an 11yo should be posting their home address on the internet.

Comment: Really, I think this post says it all: Trust the kids, educate them. The illusion of trusting them is just that, an illusion. http://superuser.com/questions/46034/protecting-kids-online?rq=1 Playing dictator and tracking their every movement helps no one. If the child can not be trusted, remove the computers or only let the child use the web with real supervision.

Comment: You are a helicopter / hell parent. You scare me and your actions seem creepy and stalkerish. Like even the babysitter? My god.

Comment: Software is not a solution for bad parenting or education. Also software recommendations at off topic.

Comment: Thanks, I am definitely OT. Next time will try to be more generic about benefits of hosted solutions versus MITM I can administer or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend [Spector Pro for Mac](http://www.spectorsoft.com/products/Spector_Macintosh/) or [eBlaster for Mac](http://www.spectorsoft.com/products/eBlaster_Mac/).

Comment: A note to others, Spector Pro does have the reports sent from Spector. In other words, it phones home with all your data. eBlaster does not have this feature.